# Sort array by Object Property on javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have this code and i need to **sort** each **element** of the array by  **area**.

```js
function Rectangle(base, altura) {
  this.base = base;
  this.altura = altura;

  this.area = function () {
    return this.base * this.altura;
  };

  this.perimetre = function () {
    return 2 * (this.base + this.altura);
  };

  this.toString = function () {
    return (
      '(b= ' +
      this.base +
      ', h= ' +
      this.altura +
      ', a = ' +
      this.area() +
      ', p =' +
      this.perimetre() +
      ')'
    );
  };
}
var rectangles = [
  new Rectangle(1, 1),
  new Rectangle(2, 2.05),
  new Rectangle(2, 5),
  new Rectangle(1, 3),
  new Rectangle(4, 4),
  new Rectangle(2, 8)
];
```

I need to do it by first declaring the **function** in the Array class of javascript and then sort it by using the **sort()** method.

```js
array.prototype.ordenaPerArea = function() {
            
};
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Should `array.prototype.ordenaPerArea()` directly modify the original array or create an ordered copy, without modifying the original one? By the way, are you sure that adding a method to the array prototype is the best way to proceed? Is there any particular reason for not using a "normal function" (I mean something like `ordenaPerArea(arr)`)?

Comment: @iota yes it was perfect thanks, but the other one was more complete!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is:

#### Method modifying the original array:

```js
function Rectangle(base, altura) {
  this.base = base;
  this.altura = altura;

  this.area = function() {
    return this.base * this.altura;
  };

  this.perimetre = function() {
    return 2 * (this.base + this.altura);
  };

  this.toString = function() {
    return (
      '(b= ' +
      this.base +
      ', h= ' +
      this.altura +
      ', a = ' +
      this.area() +
      ', p =' +
      this.perimetre() +
      ')'
    );
  };
}

var rectangles = [
  new Rectangle(1, 1),
  new Rectangle(2, 2.05),
  new Rectangle(2, 5),
  new Rectangle(1, 3),
  new Rectangle(4, 4),
  new Rectangle(2, 8)
];
console.log('rectangles (before):');
rectangles.forEach(item => console.log(item.area()));

Array.prototype.ordenaPerArea = function() {
  return this.sort(function(rectA, rectB) {
    return rectA.area() - rectB.area();
  });
}

rectangles.ordenaPerArea();

console.log('rectangles (after):');
rectangles.forEach(item => console.log(item.area()));
```

#### Method returning an ordered copy of the original array:

```js
function Rectangle(base, altura) {
  this.base = base;
  this.altura = altura;

  this.area = function() {
    return this.base * this.altura;
  };

  this.perimetre = function() {
    return 2 * (this.base + this.altura);
  };

  this.toString = function() {
    return (
      '(b= ' +
      this.base +
      ', h= ' +
      this.altura +
      ', a = ' +
      this.area() +
      ', p =' +
      this.perimetre() +
      ')'
    );
  };
}
var rectangles = [
  new Rectangle(1, 1),
  new Rectangle(2, 2.05),
  new Rectangle(2, 5),
  new Rectangle(1, 3),
  new Rectangle(4, 4),
  new Rectangle(2, 8)
];
console.log('rectangles (before):');
rectangles.forEach(item => console.log(item.area()));

Array.prototype.ordenaPerArea = function() {
  return this.map(item => item).sort(function(rectA, rectB) {
    return rectA.area() - rectB.area();
  });
}

const orderedRectangles = rectangles.ordenaPerArea();


console.log('orderedRectangles:');
orderedRectangles.forEach(item => console.log(item.area()));
console.log('rectangles (after):');
rectangles.forEach(item => console.log(item.area()));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use just subtract the areas for comparing.

```js
function Rectangle(base, altura) {
  this.base = base;
  this.altura = altura;
  this.area = function() {
    return (this.base * this.altura);
  }
  this.perimetre = function() {
    return 2 * (this.base + this.altura);
  }
  this.toString = function() {
    return "(b= " + this.base + ", h= " + this.altura + ", a = " +
      this.area() + ", p =" + this.perimetre() + ")";
  }
}
var rectangles = [
  new Rectangle(1, 1),
  new Rectangle(2, 2.05),
  new Rectangle(2, 5),
  new Rectangle(1, 3),
  new Rectangle(4, 4),
  new Rectangle(2, 8)
];
rectangles.sort((a, b) => a.area() - b.area());
rectangles.forEach(x => console.log(x.toString()));
```

If you really need to modify Array's prototype, you could, but it is not recommended.

```js
function Rectangle(base, altura) {
  this.base = base;
  this.altura = altura;
  this.area = function() {
    return (this.base * this.altura);
  }
  this.perimetre = function() {
    return 2 * (this.base + this.altura);
  }
  this.toString = function() {
    return "(b= " + this.base + ", h= " + this.altura + ", a = " +
      this.area() + ", p =" + this.perimetre() + ")";
  }
}
var rectangles = [
  new Rectangle(1, 1),
  new Rectangle(2, 2.05),
  new Rectangle(2, 5),
  new Rectangle(1, 3),
  new Rectangle(4, 4),
  new Rectangle(2, 8)
];
Array.prototype.ordenaPerArea = function(){
  return this.sort((a, b) => a.area() - b.area());
}
rectangles.ordenaPerArea();
rectangles.forEach(x => console.log(x.toString()));
```